# Openshift: unable to reach GitHub for running S2I

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I have executed Openshift Origin with
oc cluster up --version=latest
I can see that a new version has been pulled (**v3.6.0-alpha.1+7044e57-29**). However since then, I'm not able to build any image. For example:

`oc new-app --name=myapp openshift/wildfly~https://github.com/openshiftdemos/os-sample-java-web.git`

Result:

```
error: build error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/openshiftdemos/': Could not resolve host: github.com; Unknown error
```

I've tried running oc cluster up with root as well but result didn't change. Anything changed with the latest release ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use latest stable release?
If this still do not work this may be version of your docker.
Try to install latest stable release and then check your docker version.

Answer (score 1):

May the configuration behind a firewall? If so, try setting HTTP_PROXY_HOST and HTTP_PROXY_PORT environment variables.

Details can be accessed from [here](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/admin_guide/http_proxies.html).

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
sudo oc cluster down
sudo iptables -F
sudo oc cluster up
```

see also https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/12110